# What's the best low cost ways to host your own "play in browser" games

Tags: hosting

I've been developing games as a hobbiest/part-time indie for a few years now and have half a dozen games that I'm reasonably proud of. I was wondering if anyone could suggest good, relatively low cost options for setting up a web-site to host my games, playable natively in the browser, to more easily share them with friends, online communities, and potential employers.

Comment: Amazon aws ec2 instances are a good start. They have a free tier to learn and get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just simple offline browser games that don't require any kind of interaction with a server, you can use github pages.
You can easily set up a "demo" branch containing all your dependencies (if you didn't commit them into the project in the first place).

This has the added benefit of making it easy for your potential employers to check your source code :)

More info: https://pages.github.com/
Example (built on the master branch): https://github.com/bdaenen/dungemoji

Another option would be hosting them on https://itch.io. This is slightly less straightforward as you need to upload a zip file containing all the required files and your game is loaded in an iframe. The advantage here is that your games can be discovered by a relatively large audience.

More info: https://itch.io/developers
Example: https://vassildador.itch.io/

(disclaimer: the linked games/pages are mine, I only intend for them to be used as an example, not as self-promotion.)

Comment: Just wondering, what kind of builds does itch.io support? Executables? Only hml5? I mean, I suppose you cant upload a windows build and expect it to run on every machine.

Comment: itch.io only offers in-browser gameplay for unity webGL and HTML5 projects.
Non-html projects have the opportunity to upload multiple executables, which can then be downloaded and ran by a user.